# How to detect addressBar's position on IOS 15 Safari

Tags: javascript, css, mobile-safari, ios15

Now IOS 15 Safari has a default behivour of placing it's address bar at the bottom (Not floating). How can I detect it if it's on bottom or top by JS or CSS? Totally no clue...